# Faster way to refresh CF9/Fusebox 5 site CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fusebox, coldspring

Inherited a CF9 site that uses `Fusebox 5`, `Coldspring` and `CFUnit`. I've set the mode in `fusebox.xml.cfm` to:

```
<parameter name="mode" value="development-circuit-load">
```

However my CFC files seem cached (all cache options in CF admin are unchecked).
So I added the following parameters to the URL:

> &fusebox.password=*****&fusebox.load=true&fusebox.loadclean=true&fusebox.parse=true

The above parameters do cause the changes I make to a CFC to be "picked up" and *not cached*. Which is what I want. But it's making loading the page much longer.

Is there a way to refresh changes made to a CFC faster (while using `Fusebox 5` & `Coldspring`)?

I'm a `Fusebox 5` & `Coldspring` newbie, so please provide an ABC step response if you can :)

Comment: Can you supply the code that you use for the CFCs? Are they tied to `session`s or `application`s